# Continuity equation for the estimation of cosmological dimensionless parameters

Tags: cosmology, astronomy, universe, density, differential-equations

I want to set up a system of equations to find the dimensionless density parameters $\Omega_i$ as a function of $N=\ln(a)$, from the continuity equation:
$$\dot{\rho_i}+3H(p_i+\rho_i)=0$$

where the state equation is given for $p_i=\gamma_i \rho_i$. I have already tried to write the parameter $\rho_i=\Omega_i \, \rho_c$ and then apply chain rule:
$$\dot{\rho_i}=\Omega_i\, \dot{\rho_c}+ \dot{\Omega_i}\, \rho_c$$

and then substitute the derivatives with respect to time for those with respect to N, from the chain rule:

$$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{df}{dN}\frac{dN}{dt}=\frac{df}{dN}H$$

but I have not reached the expected expression. I read in a book that you can also use the parametric Friedmann equation but it is not clear to me how to do it.

Any suggestions on how to set up the system of equations and solve it?